# Visual Studio C++ Post Build Command not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, ide, xcopy

I am trying to copy my res folder from my project directory to my output directory but it's not working. I am not getting any errors by visual studio, it compiles and runs but doesn't copy. How do I copy the res folder from my project directory to my output directory so I don't have to manually copy it every time when I add new files to my project?

My post build command is:

```
xcopy /E "$(ProjectDir)res" "$(OutDir)"
```

Put in the post build events of the visual studio project

Comment: Is option /e instead of /E ? Is there path"$(ProjectDir)res" correct? res is touching to path string

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

Comment: captilization doesn't matter, still doesn't work

Comment: I have another question as well. The specified path "$(ProjectDir)res". It should be Resolved to something like "C:\xyz\res"

Comment: No the $(ProjectDir)res works fine, verified it in the output. It has the word "Dir" at the end meaning its already post-fixed with a \

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to Microsoft Docs about [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy).

> /e    Copies all subdirectories, even if they are empty. Use /e with the
> /s and /t command-line options.

For example:

I manually created the `res` folder in the `ConsoleApplication1` folder. The `res` folder contains `test.txt`. I typed `xcopy "$(ProjectDir)res" "$(OutDir)" /e`. Then it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to copy all subdirectories I only want to copy that single res folder to the output directory

Comment: I revised the answer. Hope it can help you